# Spock stubbing not working as expected. Stubbed method returning null instead of mock response

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, spock

I am trying out spock framework for writing unit test for a particular method in a service class
but not able to mock response for a method.

Service class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServiceA  {
    private final RepositoryA repositoryA;
    private final ServiceB serviceB;

    public void methodUnderTest(String arg1,String arg2){
         ObjectA objectA = repositoryA.someMethod(arg1, arg2); // here objectA is null

        if (objectA != null) {
           // Do something
        }else{
          // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to stub `repositoryA.someMethod(arg1, arg2)`  for some reason.
Its returning null while running the test.
I have tried putting both mock and stub interaction in then block as suggested in another question but its not working for me.

Test class

```
class ServiceATest extends Specification {
    @Shared ServiceA serviceA;

    @Shared RepositoryA repositoryA =  Mock(RepositoryA)
    @Shared ServiceB serviceB = Mock(ServiceB)


    def "test"() {
        given:
        serviceA = new ServiceA(repositoryA, serviceB);
        
        ObjectA mockResponse = ObjectA.builder()
                .field1("demo")
                .field2("demo")
                .field3(Instant.now().plus(3, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
                .build();

        when:
        serviceA.methodUnderTest(arg1,arg2);

        then:
        1 * repositoryA.someMethod(arg1,arg2) >> mockResponse // this is not working as expected
    }
}
```

Comment: This started working fine if i remove @Shared annotation from the spec.
Not sure why though.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. Nobody can reproduce your problem without first creating 5 helper classes and two missing variables.

Answer (score 0):

Spock manual, chapter [Scope of Interactions](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/all_in_one.html#_scope_of_interactions):

> Interactions are always scoped to a particular feature method. Hence they cannot be declared in a static method, `setupSpec` method, or `cleanupSpec` method. Likewise, mock objects should not be stored in static or `@Shared` fields.

Why would you even want to share a mock? Sharing state is bad test design and should only be used as sparingly as possible for expensive objects. Mocks are cheap. Simply resist the reflex to make everything `@Shared`, especially mocks. This kind of premature optimisation is equivalent to shooting your own foot.

For reference, here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your situation. It would have been your job to provide one:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77973193

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.time.Instant
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

class ServiceATest extends Specification {
  ServiceA serviceA
  RepositoryA repositoryA = Mock(RepositoryA)
  ServiceB serviceB = Mock(ServiceB)

  def "test"() {
    given:
    serviceA = new ServiceA(repositoryA, serviceB)
    String arg1 = "one"
    String arg2 = "two"

    ObjectA mockResponse = ObjectA.builder()
      .field1("demo")
      .field2("demo")
      .field3(Instant.now().plus(3, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
      .build()

    when:
    serviceA.methodUnderTest(arg1, arg2)

    then:
    1 * repositoryA.someMethod(arg1, arg2) >> mockResponse
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77973193

class ServiceB {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77973193

class ServiceA {
  RepositoryA repositoryA
  ServiceB serviceB

  ServiceA(RepositoryA repositoryA, ServiceB serviceB) {
    this.repositoryA = repositoryA
    this.serviceB = serviceB
  }

  void methodUnderTest(String s1, String s2) {
    repositoryA.someMethod(s1, s2)
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77973193

import java.time.Instant

class RepositoryA {
  ObjectA someMethod(String s1, String s2) {
    ObjectA.builder()
      .field1(s1)
      .field2(s2)
      .field3(Instant.now())
      .build()
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77973193

import java.time.Instant

class ObjectA {
  String field1
  String field2
  Instant field3

  static Builder builder() {
    new Builder()
  }

  static class Builder {
    ObjectA instance = new ObjectA()

    Builder field1(String value) {
      instance.field1 = value
      this
    }

    Builder field2(String value) {
      instance.field2 = value
      this
    }

    Builder field3(Instant value) {
      instance.field3 = value
      this
    }

    ObjectA build() {
      instance
    }
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_4_0&codez=eNqVVD1v2zAQ3fUrDpqowiAgaTBSoAHsdukQFIiboVPBSGebiUSqIi23CPzfS1GkQsl20i4CeXfv3dejGlY8sx1CiVQV7aH-WTOlsaVKG4fssN1W8kh_LZc3yzy9yaOI141sNahGFs-0YmJHNw0WfMsLprkU3v_EOkY1r5F-FYZL6HOHxt7CKvp530ohHwTXUVRUTCnYYNvxAlffUWnA3xpFaYxhHniJYAwD5Q7Gdo-NVFzL9s8K2uD8Ce5MxSRwJ68Ma8-w9nHekUQmqsQtxNrUEpPEJgbY8Q7FR3v0yQ1U4HEsigTZFyN_YiEb3XKxA9buUoOKpcB4Zs96uz7KOLKOb49PWOgV1Ka2ezTDFwpNhDPTxwOvSmzJwA5AtxyrMiVxibWMp9bsojUnbk9UyCNJaFMdFMkX8Lob-mX1Y5OMKJuSJEN5x_18GLRGvZflgzBl9Vskfa8L25nD6BGTwodwVVTJGu8sPETB7e2kfQM9RaeZYtbwMjet7MauyOKSBKJAWeQKbnEO88rQe67oVHnThC4kUNyYuW_JfDrJS5gP0GlDmXn4Y-ZzXpleH2uC_KSuPk03sLDXnteLLmB8q4j3xKjSuRCH2q6K8Exrk4376uyPYKhlSDS7Z-buaAdD3o_Y3DUvYD3UCmPNrpf-Ia-DPk4BZkjvkZPegdtEBbp_gTP7Z-IxbiCuyo5VB_SJYaRwYzNMNsB5e-nY4-kCZfZPlNn_UI4reZszf4fTz8dt8ozFxQ4L_gu1RA68).